# Show the difference between two averages with ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, visualization, data-wrangling

In my dataset I have two columns, named part_1 and part_2, that contain several numerical values.

I am required to create a graph that shows how the average varies in the two parts.

I think that the best way is to create a barplot with a bar for each part, but I'm not sure about it.

First, I created two new columns that contain the mean values for the two parts in each row:

`averages <- my_data %>%  mutate(avg_part1=mean(part_1,na.rm=T)) %>%  mutate(avg_part2=mean(part_2,na.rm=T))`

Then, I inserted the values in two new variables:

`avg_part1 <- averages %>% slice(1) %>% pull(avg_part1) avg_part2 <- averages %>% slice(1) %>% pull(avg_part2)`

To create the plot I did:

`to_graph<-c("First part"=avg_part1,"Second part"=avg_part2) barplot(to_graph)`

And I obtained the graph I wanted, but it's not very nice to see.

I feel like this process is too complex and I may be able to do everything in a couple lines and without creating so many new variables, do you have any suggestions?

Also, I would prefer to create the graph with ggplot because it's better to improve the design, but I don't really know how to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: please include your sample data using `dput`.

Answer (score 0):

Using ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr) 

my_data %>%  
  stack(select = c(part_1, part_2)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(values, x=ind)) + geom_bar(stat="summary", fun=mean)
```